# "TLS session of data connection has not resumed or the session does not match the control connection" error

Tags: c#, ssl, ftp

Pre-running code. But now he's making a mistake. 
The error is "TLS does not match the control connection". I get an error during client.Upload ().
I am developing with c #. In Filezilla application, the same process works without problems. error during upload. What should I do?

```
using (Ftp client = new Ftp())
            {
                client.ServerCertificateValidate += ValidateCertificate;
                client.ConnectSSL(Host);
                client.Login(Username, Password); 
                client.Upload(dosyaAdi, LocalDestinationFilename);
              }
```

Comment: What FTP library are you using?

Comment: using Limilabs.FTP.Client;

Comment: So why do you ask here? Contact their support -- Your FTP server requires TLS session resumption. I didn't find any mention of that in their online documentation.

Comment: The same project on another computer is running smoothly. It does not give a TLS error and is performing the Update process. Previously the project was running smoothly.

Comment: What another computer? Another server or another client? + Does the class support any kind of logging? + Or do you have an access to FTP server log file?

Comment: I am not having errors with the FileZilla server. I'm just getting an error in c #. When I run C # on another computer, it still works properly. The application is updating to ftp on computer A. But B is giving error on computer

Comment: Do you have any logs or not?

Comment: No, when I compile the code, the "client.update () method fails. The error text is this: TLS data connection session not resumed or does not match session control connection

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've entered port 2121. client.connect (Host, 2121); shaped. Problem solved. He made this mistake because of the port.

```
using (Ftp client = new Ftp())
            {
                client.ServerCertificateValidate += ValidateCertificate;
                client.Connect(Host,2121);
                client.Login(Username, Password); 
                client.Upload(dosyaAdi, LocalDestinationFilename);
              }
```